# adding PtrSafe to vba function call into 3rd party dll causes error in 64-bit Excel

Tags: excel, vba, 64-bit

I have a VBA project that makes 3 calls into a 3rd party dll, as follows:

```
Private Declare Function cm_checkprotection Lib "ACPPYRAMID.DLL" Alias "CM_CheckProtection" (ByVal options As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function cm_getextendederror Lib "ACPPYRAMID.DLL" Alias "CM_GetExtendedError" (ByVal ExtErr As Any) As Long
Private Declare Function cm_getproductkeya Lib "ACPPYRAMID.DLL" Alias "CM_GetProductKeyA" (ByVal ProductKey As Any) As Long
```

I am trying to port this project into 64-bit Excel, but when I add 'PtrSafe' to the declaration, Excel barfs with a "Expected: Expression" error, as shown in the attached image.

[image: 64-bit Excel Error]

Any idea  how to address this issue?

TIA,

Frank

Comment: If you would have typed `PtrSafe Declare` in Google, you would have got your answer...

Comment: OR if you would have looked couple of lines down in your code, you would have got your answer...`Private Declare PtrSafe Function Shellexecute...` ;)

Comment: @SiddharthRout - even just searching `VBA PtrSafe` returns the [MS Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ptrsafe-keyword) on it as the first result.

Comment: To answer your *next* question, it's also `LongPtr`, not `PtrLong`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shift the position to

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function
```